# How to use OVN in openstack kolla?

Tags: openstack, openstack-neutron

i am trying to install OVN using kolla-ansible but i cannot find any useful resource and is there any difference between OVS / OVN.

Comment: OVN is built on top of OVS. OVN is supported in kolla-ansible: https://docs.openstack.org/kolla-ansible/latest/reference/networking/neutron.html

Answer (score 0):

**OVN** is virtual networking for Open vSwitch and is developed within the OVS project. it is Linux foundation collaborative project.The first release of OVN comes with OVS 2.6

**OVS** is Open vSwitch.
Open vSwitch is a production quality, multilayer virtual switch licensed under the open source Apache 2.0 license.  It is designed to enable massive network automation through programmatic extension, while still supporting standard management interfaces and protocols (e.g. NetFlow, sFlow, IPFIX, RSPAN, CLI, LACP, 802.1ag).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question, please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)